# Update List View When Clicked on RecycleView Item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I created a listView which is updated on click on item in Reycleview within same page.
Date fetch is working,json data is getting and updated in adpater,but new items is extended with previous data in listview

**Layout**

[image]

First row is RecycleView and Below is Listview, Listview should be update when click on item above in recycleview

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.sharanjit.fitness.R;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AllExercise extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    GetJSONData getJSONData;
    String[] name = {"Abdominals","Arms","Back","Chest","Shoulders","Legs","Cardio"};
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    AllExerciseAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Exercise> arrayList;
    boolean first=true;
    int pos=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.allexercises);
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        context=getApplicationContext();
        getJSONData=new GetJSONData();
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager =  new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        new FetchData().execute();

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exercise_list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(AllExercise.this,ExerciseView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();

        if(id==16908332)
        {
            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public ImageView imageView;
            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView11);

            }
        }

        public MyAdapter() {

        }

        @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.exercise_item, parent, false);
          final  ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            vh.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pos=vh.getAdapterPosition();
                    first=false;
                    new FetchData().execute();
                }
            });
            return vh;
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder=holder;
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(Constants.exercise_images[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return 7;
        }
    }
    public class AllExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {


        final private Context cx;

        final private int pos;

        AllExerciseAdapter(Context cx,int pos) {

            super(cx, R.layout.allexercise_list_item, arrayList);

            this.cx = cx;

            this.pos=pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View vw, ViewGroup group) {
            vw = View.inflate(cx, R.layout.allexercise_list_item, null);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)vw.findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
            TextView title=(TextView)vw.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
            TextView cat=(TextView)vw.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

            title.setText(arrayList.get(position).names);
            cat.setText(arrayList.get(position).category);
            if(position==0)
                Log.e("MS",title.getText().toString());

            return vw;
        }
    }

    private class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String url="";
        String data="";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("In Progress...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
            url="http://www.searchdata.in/fitness/get-exercises.php";
            try {

             data = URLEncoder.encode("category", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name[pos], "UTF-8");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s=  getJSONData.getData(url,data);
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            Log.e("sss",s);

            try {
                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(s);
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Exercise exercise=new Exercise();
                    exercise.names=object.getString("name");
                    exercise.category=object.getString("category");
                    exercise.decription=object.getString("description");
                    arrayList.add(exercise);
                }
                    dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("ss",""+first);
            adapter = new AllExerciseAdapter(context,pos);
            if(!first) {
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                      }
else {
                list.setAdapter(adapter);




            }
        }
    }

    private class Exercise
    {
        public String names;
        public String decription;
        public String category;
        public String imagePath;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @Nisarg no error, i am getting the new data extended with the previous data, i want to replace the previous data with the new data

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a small change in your code -

```
if(!first) {
          list.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // No needed to do for first time
}
else {
          list.setAdapter(adapter); // Need to call only once.
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Here you need to call it to reflect changes   

 }
```

One more change you need to do in onPostExecute -

```
try {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(s);
            arraList.clear();   //Add this line
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Still Not working, new data is extending with the previous one. i am using this as u have told:-

    `if(!first) {
          list.setAdapter(adapter);
          
}
else {
          list.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Here you need to call it to reflect changes   

 }`

Comment: No need to call setAdapter all the time, you just need to call notifyDataSetChanged() every-time you are making any changes in arrayList.

Comment: Let me know if you are still facing any problem :)

Comment: Yeah i have done exactly the way u have said but still i am getting the same thing.
`adapter = new AllExerciseAdapter(context,arrayList);
if (first)
list.setAdapter(adapter);
else
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if any more problem you facing :)

Comment: I think the code line is incomplete, new JSON response is getting but it extends the previous data

Comment: You need to clear the old data, just add arrayList.clear() as I have suggested in my answer. It will remove the old data and just show you the fresh data.

Comment: Now the Data is showing but only when i scroll down the listview not on OnClick, when item goes out of the screen while scrolling then it is updated but i want the data to be updated on click.

Comment: If you are calling notifyDataSetChanged and still getting the same problem, just update your post with your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your onPostExecute method by below code.

```
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.e("sss",s);

        try {
            arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(s);
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject object=array.getJSONObject(i);
                Exercise exercise=new Exercise();
                exercise.names=object.getString("name");
                exercise.category=object.getString("category");
                exercise.decription=object.getString("description");
                arrayList.add(exercise);
            }
                dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("ss",""+first);
        adapter = new AllExerciseAdapter(context,pos);

         list.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*if(!first) 
         {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         }
         else {
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
         }*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Line Is working for the code:-

```
adapter = new AllExerciseAdapter(context,arrayList);
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); // <-----
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```